# Mysql : Add values of columns in table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this structure in my table

```
id|source_id|val1|val2
1 |1        |10  |NULL
2 |1        |NULL|3
3 |2        |NULL|5
4 |2        |4   |NULL
5 |3        |7   |NULL
```

ANd i want to have this in mysql

```
source_id|total
1        |13
2        |9
3        |7
```

Can you help me please

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Use [`Ifnull()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull) function to replace `null` values with 0.
- Use [`Sum()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum) function to sum both val1 and val2 in a single expression, using `Group By` on source_id.

Do the following:

```
SELECT ressource_id, 
       SUM(IFNULL(val1, 0)) + SUM(IFNULL(val2, 0)) AS total 
FROM your_table 
GROUP BY ressource_id
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you want:

```
select source_id, coalesce(sum(val1), 0) + coalesce(sum(val2), 0)
from t 
group by source_id;
```

I would do the `NULL` conversion *after* the `SUM()`, because some `source_id`s only have `NULL`s in one of the columns.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT q.resource_id, 
       ( q.val1 + q.val2 ) AS total 
FROM  (SELECT resource_id, 
              Ifnull(Sum(val1), 0) AS val1, 
              Ifnull(Sum(val2), 0) AS val2 
       FROM   `table` 
       GROUP  BY resource_id) AS q
```